# Pyspark LDA: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql, lda

I installed pyspark and getting a type error when trying to initialize spark context.

Pyspark installation:
[image]

The code is as below:

```
 import pyspark
from collections import defaultdict
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA, LDAModel
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# Initialize
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
```

Error message is as below:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bedceba80d96> in <module>()
      7 
      8 # Initialize
----> 9 sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
     10 sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

c:\users\vishn\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

c:\users\vishn\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.pyc in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    186         self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
    187         (host, port) = self._accumulatorServer.server_address
--> 188         self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
    189         self._jsc.sc().register(self._javaAccumulator)
    190 

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Comment: The problem is not obvious. Do you have code that was left out? Also, are you running this code in `pyspark` shell or anything based on it? Which version of spark are you running (2.2.1?)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele The above shown is the complete code. I'm running in Jupyter notebook. Spark version - 2.0.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Jupyter  notebook and Jupyter lab, on OS X 10.11.6 with Java java version "1.8.0_05".  If I run iPython and use FindSpark and then SparkContext, then 'sc' in my Jupyter notebook works.

Comment: I also have the same problem with Jupyter notebook on centos 7. If I run it by root user I live hdfs permission problem. If I run it with spark user then this error happens.